# Who Is Rabbi Eliezer Yosef ben Rabbi Yitzchak HaLevi Letterberg לטרברג?

Tags: sources-mekorot, cemetery-grave, gravestone-inscription

Someone told me that's it's written on the tombstone of רבי אליעזר יוסף בן רבי יצחק הלוי לטרברג:

"הרבץ תורה ברבים ולמד וחזיר בעל פה למעלה מארבעת אלפים פעם מסכת ביצה וראש השנה"

Who is רבי אליעזר יוסף בן רבי יצחק הלוי לדרברג?

Comment: See http://www.chabad.org.il/Magazines/Article.asp?ArticleID=624&CategoryID=419 (do a search for לדרברג to find it) for this quote.

Comment: @Scimonster: How do you spell לדרברג in english?

Comment: The page is in Hebrew, so do the search in Hebrew.

Comment: Google is very helpful here - the top result for רבי אליעזר יוסף בן רבי יצחק הלוי לטרברג is this question. :P

Comment: [Kevarim.com](http://kevarim.com/index/) shows inscriptions for many kevarim in North America.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=eVhzJ7VB3GQC&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29#v=onepage&q&f=false). He was a store keeper who lived in Jerusalem who passed away in 1954. More on him [here](http://torahactionlife.com/2095/weekly-parasha/parasha-archive/chukat-5773-devotion-to-torah).

He is notable for the singular accomplishment of reviewing ראש השנה and ביצה over 4000 times.

Comment: Thank you for the information! Is there a website that has picture of his tombstone?